# Does BLT2.5 work with Tcl8.6?

Tags: plot, tcl, tk-toolkit

I work with a project in Tcl that started with Tcl8.4. The latest 'official' BLT (version 2.4) is a dependency.

We have since upgraded to Tcl8.5, which breaks some of the BLT2.4 stuff that we've made do without. I'd also like to upgrade to Tcl8.6 soon.

BLT has since been branched to fix this issue (see [here](http://wiki.tcl.tk/199)).

Does amyone know if the branched "BLT-2.5" work with Tcl8.6? The TCL wiki says this is not known.

Alternatively, if I can't on compatibility with BLT when upgrading Tcl, I can take the time to move to something else for 2D plotting (such as VTK or plplot), but if I can count on BLT for Tcl8.6, then it's the path of least resistance for the project.

Comment: Doesn't look promising to me.  The code on sourceforge hasn't been updated in 5 years.  I would find a product that has better support.

Comment: It _might_ work… and I'd be interested in hearing of anyone's experiences with this. There was substantial surgery on Tcl's internals in 8.6, but as long as the things that require the non-recursive execution (NRE) engine aren't used, they probably won't bite. It's not like the reengineering of variables that happened in 8.5 (and which was the cause of the problems for BLT).

Comment: I downloaded and installed [Tk8.6-blt2.5](https://packages.debian.org/sid/tk8.6-blt2.5) on ubuntu 14.04 and quickly went through the examples in blt-demo. The stuff I'm interested (plotting utilities) in all worked with Tcl8.6, but there were a few X errors, a few seg faults, and a few script-level errors.